# Refactoring react project to make it load data from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I have following project sturcture:

```
public
src
package.json
server.js
```

Inside the src folder I have following:

```
components
data
routes
styles
views
App.js
index.js
```

In ***components*** folder I have all components such as *AsidePost*, *Filter*, *MainNav* and so on.

In ***views*** folder I have components that include other components from ***components*** folder.

In ***data*** folder I have all the data for my components.

In ***routes*** folder I have *Routes.js* component which imports all views and does bilds a view to a particualr route:

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MainNav />
      <div className="page-content">
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
            ...and so on...
            <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
} 

export default Routes
```

In *Home* component I import *Card* component

```
import Card from '../components/Card'
```

and import *data*

```
import { cardsData } from '../data/cardsData'
```

for each of item in my *cardsData* i render a *Card* component and give this component data from item:

```
        {cardsData.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <Card data={item}
                  key={i} />
          )
        })}
```

So, I build this project with webpack and got a single file bundle.js.
This is code from my *server.js* file in main folder:

```
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html')
})
app.listen(3000)
```

So, this is how it works now. I want to change this project and make something like this: connect to mongodb database, using mongoose, create, for example Card model and then in ***Home*** view component render Card component and give this component data not from ***CardsData.js*** file but from database.

I know, how to use mongoose and how load data from there, but I don't understand how the file structure should looks like and where in my code should I connect to database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to connect directly from your react app to your database. And even if you could find a way, it'll be a major security risk to your app.

What you can do on the other hand is setup a nodejs server (or whatever language you prefer on the server side).
This server will expose REST endpoints to execute actions on this data (Like the standard Create Read Update Delete

There is lots of help online to find how to create REST endpoints. And once done, all you have to do is use these endpoints to collect required data using ajax requests inside your react components.

Another way to do it is using backendless services such as firebase and consort. They offer you a secured database, already available as RESTs endpoints.

Regarding your specific architecture, you can create a single folder named server that will contain all server related code. Personnaly I like to separate the server side into the classic Controllers/Repository/Models architecture. You don't need views as you are only serving JSON, but that may vary if you have to actually do the formatiing of models to JSON yourself.